# Validate header of file in linux

Tags: bash, shell, perl, awk, scripting

I am using below script to validate header of file. For which i have created one file which is having only header and comparing it with another file which is having data for column along with the header.

```
awk -F"|" 'FNR==NR{hn=split($0,header); next}
     FNR==1 {n=split($0,fh)
            for(i=0;i<=hn; i++)
                if (fh[i]!=header[i]) {
                   printf "%s:order of %s is not correct\n",FILENAME, header[i]
                 next}
            if (hn==n)
                print FILENAME, "has expected order of fields"
        else
                print FILENAME, "has extra fields"
next
                }' key /Scripts/gst/Kenan_Test_Scenarios1.txt
```

Sample file header(Key)
`SourceIdentifier|SourceFileName|GLAccountCode|Division|SubDivision|ProfitCentre1|ProfitCentre2|PlantCode|ReturnPeriod|SupplierGSTIN|DocumentType|SupplyType|DocumentNumber|DocumentDate|OriginalDocumentNumber|OriginalDocumentDate|CRDRPreGST|LineNumber|CustomerGSTIN|UINorComposition|OriginalCustomerGSTIN|CustomerName|CustomerCode|BillToState|ShipToState|POS|PortCode|ShippingBillNumber|ShippingBillDate|FOB|ExportDuty|HSNorSAC|ProductCode|ProductDescription|CategoryOfProduct|UnitOfMeasurement|Quantity|TaxableValue|IntegratedTaxRate|IntegratedTaxAmount|CentralTaxRate|CentralTaxAmount|StateUTTaxRate|StateUTTaxAmount|CessRateAdvalorem|CessAmountAdvalorem|CessRateSpecific|CessAmountSpecific|InvoiceValue|ReverseChargeFlag|TCSFlag|eComGSTIN|ITCFlag|ReasonForCreditDebitNote|AccountingVoucherNumber|AccountingVoucherDate|Userdefinedfield1|Userdefinedfield2|Userdefinedfield3`

File 2 header along with data(Kenan_Test_Scenarios1.txt)

```
SourceIdentifier|SourceFileName|GLAccountCode|Division|SubDivision|ProfitCentre1|ProfitCentre2|PlantCode|ReturnPeriod|SupplierGSTIN|DocumentType|SupplyType|DocumentNumber|DocumentDate|OriginalDocumentNumber|OriginalDocumentDate|CRDRPreGST|LineNumber|CustomerGSTIN|UINorComposition|OriginalCustomerGSTIN|CustomerName|CustomerCode|BillToState|ShipToState|POS|PortCode|ShippingBillNumber|ShippingBillDate|FOB|ExportDuty|HSNorSAC|ProductCode|ProductDescription|CategoryOfProduct|UnitOfMeasurement|Quantity|TaxableValue|IntegratedTaxRate|IntegratedTaxAmount|CentralTaxRate|CentralTaxAmount|StateUTTaxRate|StateUTTaxAmount|CessRateAdvalorem|CessAmountAdvalorem|CessRateSpecific|CessAmountSpecific|InvoiceValue|ReverseChargeFlag|TCSFlag|eComGSTIN|ITCFlag|ReasonForCreditDebitNote|AccountingVoucherNumber|AccountingVoucherDate|Userdefinedfield1|Userdefinedfield2|Userdefinedfield3
KEN|TEST1|||Tela|Outw|ANP|POST|1017|36AAA|NV|TX|4841446542|2017-12-12||2035-06-11|Y|1|36AAACB89|||||||36||||||94||Telecomm Servi||||1557.20|0.00|10.00|9.00|140.15|9.00|140.15|||||18.50||||||||B2B INV||
```

Getting below output and which is not correct though header in both files are same.

```
 is not correctnan_Test_Scenarios1.txt:order of Userdefinedfield3
```

Could you please help me to rectify the code and also need to capture if multiple header names has msimatch

Comment: Can you show the result of `cat -v` on each file?  This will show any hidden control characters, new-lines, and such. I have a feeling that one of your files is in DOS format and the other not, or something like that. That would explain why your last field doesn't match even though the visible characters are the same.

Comment: Hi,Thank you Jas.. File had "^M" charater present, now i have removed it and got the script working.
But have one more issue.
Need to list all header that are not matching with another file.
Currently script is showing only first mismatch it found and not displaying the second mismatch.
/Scripts/gst/Kenan_Test_Scenarios1.txt:order of SourceIdentifier is not correct

Comment: @as7951, if you could post your samples in CODE TAGS `{}` button in better condition it will be easier for us to help you, please do so.

Comment: Do you actually need to identify incorrect/misordered headers, or is your concern making sure the data is ordered the same way as the 'key'? Because that's two slightly different questions.

Comment: Hi Sobrique,
Perhaps i need both, i need to identify the incorrect header(may be some might be containing character in small letter and some might be missing some character etc) and also need to validate the order of header data.
and need to print all the records that are mismatch, if three column header are not correct then need to print those three column headers

Comment: To list all issues just get rid of the `next` statements.

Comment: `i=0` should be `i=1` btw. Awk arrays, strings, and fields start at 1, not 0.

Answer (score 2):

OK, you've tagged this perl, so here's a perl answer. I think you're focussing on the wrong problem - why not instead read row by row, parse them into a hash, and then output your desired ordering:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

open ( my $first_file, '<', 'file_name_here' ) or die $!; 
chomp ( my @header = split /\|/, <$first_file> ); 
close ( $first_file ); 
#debugging
print Dumper \@header; 

open  ( my $second_file, '<', 'second_file_name_here' ) or die $!; 
chomp ( my @second_header = split /\|/, <$second_file> );

print join ( "|", @header ), "\n";
while ( <$second_file> ) {
    my %row;
    #use ordering of column headings to read into named fields; 
    @row{@second_header} = split /\|/;
    #debugging output to show you what's going on. 
    print Dumper \%row; 

    print join ("|", @row{@header} ), "\n";
}
```

That way you don't care if the order is wrong, because you forward fix it.

If you really need to compare, then you can iterate each of the `@header` arrays and look for differences. But that's more a question of what you're actually trying to get - I would suggest looking at [`Array::Utils`](http://search.cpan.org/~zmij/Array-Utils-0.5/Utils.pm) because that lets you trivially use `array_diff`, `intersect` and `unique`.

Answer (score 0):

this may come in handy

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines  <(tr '|' '\n' <file1) <(tr '|' '\n' <file2)
```

used your first file as is for file1 and used this

```
$ sed 's/2/8/;s/Export/Import/' file1 > file2
```

to create the second file.  Running the script gives

```
ProfitCentre2                                                 | ProfitCentre8
ExportDuty                                                    | ImportDuty
```